# Python | KeyError 'totalResults' while making the GET request JSON file

Tags: python, json, api, foursquare

I used the Foursquare explore API with categoryId to query the number of venues of each category in a specific radius. The response contains a totalResults value for the specified coordinates, radius and category.

```
def get_venues_count(latitudes, longitudes, radius, categoryId):
    explore_url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}&ll={},{}&radius={}&categoryId={}'.format(
                CLIENT_ID, 
                CLIENT_SECRET, 
                VERSION,
                lat,
                lng,
                radius,
                categoryId)

    #make the GET request
    return requests.get(explore_url).json()['response']['totalResults']

#Create new dataframe to store venues data
stations_venues_df = df.copy()
for c in categories_list:
    stations_venues_df[c[0]] = 0

#Request number of venues, store result as CSV
for i, row in stations_venues_df.iterrows():
    print(i)
    for c in categories_list:        
        stations_venues_df.loc[i, c[0]] = get_venues_count(stations_venues_df.Latitude.iloc[i],
                                                           stations_venues_df.Longitude.iloc[i],
                                                           radius=500,
                                                           categoryId=c[1])
    stations_venues_df.to_csv('stations_venues.csv')
```

I ran it many times but every time it only generated a couple of rows and then stopped and show this error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-551e888d2436> in <module>
      6                                                            stations_venues_df.Longitude.iloc[i],
      7                                                            radius=500,
----> 8                                                            categoryId=c[1])
      9     stations_venues_df.to_csv('stations_venues.csv')

<ipython-input-20-c9e33ae6e146> in get_venues_count(latitudes, longitudes, radius, categoryId)
     10 
     11     # make the GET request
---> 12     return requests.get(explore_url).json()['response']['totalResults']

KeyError: 'totalResults'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess that the returned response is invalid(or has a different json format that you're expecting).

I suggest adding a check if 'totalResults' is in the json()["reponse"] dictionary.
If not, then you'll know why and what kind of response is being returned.